# Installing deb to a different directory

Tags: software-installation, deb, steam

Is there any possible way to install steam from a .deb file to a folder on an external usb hard drive? I have tried something like "--root=" but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you are trying to do. In general there isn't an easy way, or reason to, install programs in a non-standard place in Debian. Generally if you want the files to be on a separate partition you would mount that as `/var/lib` but then your whole system would use that as the `/var/lib`  location. What is the end goal of installing the deb somewhere other than the default?

Answer (score 2):

*Installing* a package to a different location isn't supported, as a package is usually carefully constructed so that every file is placed in the correct location, and having those moved elsewhere at the whim of the user means that the appropriate files can't be found anymore. The packaging system also doesn't cater for different places for the files, so removing the package won't be possible.

If you just want to *extract* the package somewhere, then that's not a problem:

```
dpkg-deb --extract whatever.deb /some/path
```

If you also want the control information (file list, pre- and post-installation scripts, etc.) to be extracted, use:

```
dpkg-deb --raw-extract whatever.deb /some/path
```

The control information is placed in /some/path/DEBIAN/.